# EBS vs EFs vs FSx vs S3 for feeding data to a distributed machine learning model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

Lets says there are 1TB of data to be simultaneously fed to 100 EC2 consumer instances. Each instance accesses random chunks of data of size 10MB. What would be the considerations to take into account to choose between 4 different file storage systems available at AWS?

Answer (score 0):

The one question you need to answer first is what OS are those EC2 instances?  Linux, windows or a mixture of both. for Linux EFS and S3 would be fine,  S3 would be a lot cheaper.  If you have windows I would stick to EBS or FSx.  If you have a mixture of both i would consider using FSx